# How to count the number of words, characters and lines with pure C

Tags: c

I want to count the number of words, characters, new lines, no matter how my sentence looks like. (For example, even if I typed a sentence like this:

`y yafa \n \n youasf\n sd`

the program should still be able to count the number of words, lines, characters correctly). I don't know how to implement such program with pure C, can anyone help me on that?

Here is my current code, and it can only be correct under certain conditions...

```
int main() {
    int cCount = 0, wCount = 0, lCount = 0;

    printf("Please enter the sentence you want\n");

    char str[20];
    int j7 = 0;

    while (int(str[j7]) != 4) {
        str[j7] = getchar();
        if (str[0] == ' ') {
            printf("Sentence starts from a word not blank\n");
            break;
        }
        if (int(str[j7]) == 4)
            break;
        j7++;
    }
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 20) {
        if (str[count] != ' ' && str[count] != '\n') {
            cCount++;
        } else
        if (str[count] == ' ') {
            wCount++;
        } else
        if (str[count] == '\n') {
            lCount++;
        }
        count++;
    }

    printf("Characters: %d\nWords: %d\nLines: %d\n\n",
           cCount, wCount++, lCount + 1);
    int x = 0;
    std::cin >> x;
}
```

Comment: `pure C` doesn't have `std::cin`, so don't mix with C++

Comment: also try to use good variable names, not like `j7` which doesn't mean anything

Comment: For a review of your code, you may have a better chance on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If a file consisted only of 3 characters: `"abc"` and no following newline, what result would you expect?

Comment: `int(str[j7])` is not a pure C construct. Use `(int)(str[j7])`.

Comment: You also should define word and line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not writing in *Pure C*, but rather in C++.

To achieve your goal, you must summarize the problem into a sequence of logical steps:

- for each character read:

  - if the previous one is a line separator, you have a new line ;
  - if the previous one is a word separator and the current isn't, you have a new word ;
  - if all cases, you have a new character, save it as the previous character for the next iteration.

Use `'\n'` as the initial value for the `last` character, so the first character read if any starts a new line and possibly a new word if it is not whitespace.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long chars = 0, words = 0, lines = 0;

    printf("Enter the text:\n");

    for (int c, last = '\n'; (c = getchar()) != EOF; last = c) {
        chars++;
        if (last == '\n')
            lines++;
        if (isspace(last) && !isspace(c))
            words++;
    }
    printf("Characters: %ld\n"
           "Words: %ld\n"
           "Lines: %ld\n\n", chars, words, lines);
    return 0;
}
```

If you are required to use a `while` loop, the `for` loop can be converted this way:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long chars = 0, words = 0, lines = 0;
    int c, last = '\n';

    printf("Enter the text:\n");

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        chars++;
        if (last == '\n')
            lines++;
        if (isspace(last) && !isspace(c))
            words++;
        last = c;
    }
    printf("Characters: %ld\n"
           "Words: %ld\n"
           "Lines: %ld\n\n", chars, words, lines);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @4386427: Actually, I believe it does: `two\nwords` will be counted as 9 chars, 2 words, 2 lines, which is arguably more correct than the output of `wc`: `1 2 9`.

Comment: @D.Kenny: converted the `for` loop into a more error prone `while` loop.