# Counting characters, words, and lines based on a text file

Tags: c

this is the assignment: Write a C program (called counting.c) that counts the number of characters, words and lines read from standard input (stdin) until EOF is reached. This means counting.c must contain a main function along with other function.

I was able to write it, but in the main function, how do i make it into its own function that main calls? Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned long int charCount = 0;
    unsigned long int wordCount = 0;
    unsigned long int lineCount = 0;

    int wrd = 1;

    char input;

    while( (input = getchar()) != EOF ){
        //counting characters
        charCount = charCount + 1;
        
        //counts lines
        if (input == '\n'){
            lineCount = lineCount + 1;
            wrd = 1;
        }
    
        //counting words
        //"a"" is 97, "z" is 122, "A" is 65, "Z" is 90, " ' " is 39
        if ((input >= 97 && input <= 122 )||(input >= 65 && input <= 90)||input == 39){
            if (wrd == 1){
                wordCount = wordCount + 1;
                wrd = 0;
            }
        }

        else{
            wrd = 1;
        }
    
    }  

    printf( "%lu %lu %lu\n", charCount, wordCount, lineCount );
    return 0;       

}
```

Comment: Have you learnt about functions? Assuming you have since it is asked of you in this task, what specifically do you not understand about writing a function and calling it in this context?

Comment: First `char input` should be `int` the type returned by `getchar()`. Second don't use magic numbers. Instead of commenting that "a is 97" use `'a'` etc.

Comment: Does [How to count the number of words, characters and lines with pure C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41195941/3422102) not help? Or maybe [Program to count lines words and characters in c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54694657/3422102)? Additionally, don't use *MagicNumbers* in your code. Instead of `97`, use `'a'`, etc..

Comment: The lazy way: `#include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { char s[256]; const char *c = "wc %s"; if(argc != 2 || strlen(argv[1]) >= sizeof s - sizeof c) return EXIT_FAILURE; sprintf(s, c, argv[1]); return system(s); }`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin we were told to use ascii values

Comment: @Sultan That's a pretty vague statement.

Comment: `char input;` -> `int input;` or there is no guarantee you will match `EOF`. (e.g. `11111111` is not equal to `11111111111111111111111111111111` unless promoted and sign-extended) PS - do what you were told -- but know it's bad programming practice. Use character literals when specifying ASCII values to make your code readable. You may also look at [Count Lines, Words & Chars (Linux wc) in C](https://pastebin.com/MWys2raS)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Detail: C does not define character _literals_, but does define character _constants_.

Answer (score 1):

A nearly fool-proof approach it to examine the *previous* character and the current one.

This nicely handles input where the last line does not end with `'\n'`, but only end-of-file.  OP's code fails the line count in that case.

> how do i make it into its own function that main calls?

Pass in 3 pointers to save the results.

```
void count(unsigned long *charCountPtr, unsigned long *wordCountPtr, 
    unsigned long *lineCountPtr) {
  unsigned long charCount = 0;
  unsigned long wordCount = 0;
  unsigned long lineCount = 0;
  int previous = '\n';
  int ch; // Use int to accommodate 257 different responses.

  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    charCount++;
    if (previous == '\n') lineCount++;
    // ToDo: OP to write int isletter(int ch)
    if (!isletter(previous) && isletter(ch)) wordCount++;
    previous = ch;
  }

  if (charCountPtr) *charCountPtr = charCount;
  ...  // OP to finish
}
```